# Problem with @reduxjs/toolkit and react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I use redux (with RTK) for state management in my react-native application. I also use redux-persist. The following snippet of code once worked:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uploadingReducer, { setStatus } from './uploading';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducers({
  uploading: persistReducer({
    key: 'uploading',
    storage: AsyncStorage
  }, uploadingReducer),
}));

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false
  }),
});
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Then, after rebooting my computer I tried to continued working on it, but after running `react-naive start` I started getting following errors in a console:

```
 LOG  Running "MyApp" with {"rootTag":311}
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
```

And phone logs (I debug on a physical device) same error pointing to the line

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducers({
```

and to the `combineReducers` method specifically.

Before reboot I didn't do any changes to the project: I am sure of that, because I track changes with git and it worked after restoring unstaged changes which in any case were made to the native part. I also didn't do anything with Node.js neither globally nor in another project. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS. Node version is v18.10.0.

Full project dependencies are following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
```

Here's a list of my attempts to solve the problem (same error was still there). I tried:

- stopping server and starting it again
- running `npm run android` again (just in case, but as I understand react-native, it shouldn't affect on a result)
- reinstalling @reduxjs/toolkit
- removing project's `node_modules` and then running `npm ci`
- removing project's `node_modules` and then running `npm install`
- uninstalling globally installed react-native and react-native-cli (which, as far as I know, don't have to be installed globally, but I can't remember why I did it anyway). When uninstalling react-native I encountered error `ENOEMPTY` and as suggested in many answers on questions related to this error I removed `react-native` folder in the `node_modules` for globally installed packages. I thought that this additional information might be relevant to the issue
- running `npm cache clean --force` in a project root folder

What can be the root of this problem? Why it suddenly doesn't work anymore? I didn't upgrade anything. I would try to change my code to use just redux (without RTK), but I still don't understand why it doesn't work if no changes been made.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.